# how to run two batch file independently?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have two batch file "bat1.bat" and "bat2.bat" I need to write another batch file such as "third.bat" that can run "bat1.bat" and "bat2.bat" independently.(at the same time). In reality I can open two cmd and run them separately.In addition bat1 and bat2 are both in infinite loops so they never exits

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`start`](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) for that:

```
rem This is third.bat
start bat1.bat
start bat2.bat
```

Comment: sweet and also how do you use start with path file like "C:\Users\mfar\Desktop\bat1.bat

Comment: did you try `start c:\users\mfar\bat1.bat` ?

Comment: Just in case, option `/B` stands for "start... without creating a new window" or without a "Command Prompt" window. Related: https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way#comment1542914_62628